# Viewmodel always null following file upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I am creating a page in Asp.Net MVC where a user can upload a file, along with details about the file from textboxes.

For this I use a viewmodel, and a very simple method configuration. The page is populated correctly by the [Get] Method, and the user can choose the file and enter the details, but once the 'Submit' button is clicked, and the [Post] method is called, the viewmodel is completely null.

I have done my research on this and have tried:

- adding enctype="multipart/form-data"
- simply using the file as a separate parameter

To no avail.

Here is my controller methods:

```
public ActionResult FileComment(int id)
{
    //set up [get] view

    return View("FileComment", obj);
}

//THIS METHOD's VIEWMODEL ALWAYS NULL
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FileComment(CalibrationCommentViewModel file)
{
    //save file to database

    return View("Edit", new { id = file.id });
}
```

Here is part of my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileComment", "Calibration", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @data_ajax = "false" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
    <div class="container">
        <h4>Add File for @Model.ID</h4>
        <hr />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">g
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.file, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.file, new { type = "file" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9"></div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.attachmentType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.attachmentType, Model.attachTypeList, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9"></div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date)
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9"></div>
        </div>
        <br />

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.description, new { cols=35, @rows=3})
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9"></div>
        </div>

        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <button type="submit" onclick="JavascriptFunction()">Add to @Model.ID</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
public ActionResult FileComment(CalibrationCommentViewModel file)
```

to

```
public ActionResult FileComment(CalibrationCommentViewModel model)
```

Answer (score 0):

your view has no reference to view model at the top the view something like this
@model Nameofyourproject.Models.CalibrationCommentViewModel

Comment: I said that that was PART of my view. I of course included my strongly-typed model at the top.